# How to create type of func with specified generic types?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I want to create Func type with specified generic type arguments, something like that like, but only with one statement

```
Type create_type(Type[] types)
{
   return typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(types); // error if types.Length != 1
   return typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(types); // error if types.Length != 2
   return typeof(Func<,,>).MakeGenericType(types); // error if types.Length != 3
   return typeof(Func<,,,>).MakeGenericType(types); // error if types.Length != 4
// .... 
}
```

Of course, I can create auxuliary array:

```
var func_types = new Type[] { typeof(Func<>), typeof(Func<,>) , //...}
```

But this solution seems too ugly for me

Note: array of types can be long (up to 15) and I want to find elegant solution. Unfortunately, I am creating such type from meta data, written in another language

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are static Methods in Expression class for Func and Action that do exaclty what you require

```
Expression.GetFuncType(Type[] types)

Expression.GetActionType(Type[] types)
```

Further Information here:

[GetFuncType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.getfunctype(v=vs.110).aspx)

[GetActionType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.getactiontype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: that's brilliant answer!

Comment: Then I retract all my comments above about ugly code being needed :) Turns out it's just a question of who's going to have to write that ugly or convoluted code - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Compiler/DelegateHelpers.Generated.cs,227

Comment: @CSharpie, Is there some analogue of such method for tuple type?

Comment: @АлександрЛысенко It appears not, but i also dont see the point why would someone create a Tuple-Type via reflection. Tuples are designed to be used in a small (local) scope. so they should never leave the body of a method. Anything else tends to be a codesmell in the firstplace.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen, I thought that implementation will intrigue you)) https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/a.html#0788e95ecadc4631

Answer (score 2):

Recall that generic types have names of the form `` T`N ``, where `N` is the number of generic parameters. So all `Func` delegates have a systematic name that allows us to easily get the type:

```
Type create_type(Type[] types) {
    return Type.GetType($"System.Func`{types.Length}").MakeGenericType(types);
}
```

No promises as to how efficient this is, but if you're constructing such types at runtime, that's probably not the primary concern anyway.

---

Given the existence of `Expression.GetFuncType`, this answer is of course inferior, but I'm leaving it up for educational purposes (of some sort). This stops working beyond 9 arguments, because `System.Func` delegates of more than 9 arguments live in `System.Core`, not `mscorlib`, and therefore require an assembly-qualified name. The fix is easy (throw in a check and conditionally add `System.Core` to the name), but unnecessary given the existence of `GetFuncType`.